# How to redirect back to private route after login in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am building a Next.js project where I want to implement private route similar to react-private route. In React this can be done by using react-router, but in Next.js this cannot be done. next/auth has the option to create private route I guess, but I am not using next/auth.

I have created a HOC for checking if the user is logged-in or not, but I'm not able to redirect the user to the private he/she wants to go after successfully logging in. How to achieve this functionality in Next.js? Can anybody help me in this?

This is the HOC, I used the code from a blog about private routing.

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

const login = '/login'; // Define your login route address.

/**
 * Check user authentication and authorization
 * It depends on you and your auth service provider.
 * @returns {{auth: null}}
 */
const checkUserAuthentication = () => {
  const token = typeof window !== "undefined" && localStorage.getItem('test_token');
  if(!token) {
    return { auth: null };
  } else return {auth:true};
   // change null to { isAdmin: true } for test it.
};

export default WrappedComponent => {
  const hocComponent = ({ ...props }) => <WrappedComponent {...props} />;

  hocComponent.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const userAuth = await checkUserAuthentication();

    // Are you an authorized user or not?
    if (!userAuth?.auth) {
      // Handle server-side and client-side rendering.
      if (context.res) {
        context.res?.writeHead(302, {
          Location: login,
        });
        context.res?.end();
      } else {
        Router.replace(login);
      }
    } else if (WrappedComponent.getInitialProps) {
      const wrappedProps = await WrappedComponent.getInitialProps({...context, auth: userAuth});
      return { ...wrappedProps, userAuth };
    }

    return { userAuth };
  };

  return hocComponent;
};
```

This is my private route code:

```
import withPrivateRoute from "../../components/withPrivateRoute";
// import WrappedComponent from "../../components/WrappedComponent";

const profilePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is private route</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default withPrivateRoute(profilePage);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redirect back to the protected route the user was trying to access, you can pass a query parameter with the current path (protected route path) when redirecting to the login page.

```js
// Authentication HOC
const loginPath = `/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(context.asPath)}`;

if (context.res) {
    context.res.writeHead(302, {
        Location: loginPath
    });
    context.res.end();
} else {
    Router.replace(loginPath);
}
```

In the login page, once the login is complete, you can access the query parameter from `router.query.from` and use that to redirect the user back.

```js
// Login page

const login = () => {
    // Your login logic
    
    // If login is successful, redirect back to `router.query.from` 
    // or fallback to `/homepage` if login page was accessed directly
    router.push(router.query.from && decodeURIComponent(router.query.from) ?? '/homepage');
}
```

Note that `encodeURIComponent`/`decodeURIComponent` is used because the `asPath` property can contain query string parameters. These need to be encoded when passed to the login URL, and then decoded back when the URL is used to redirect back.

Comment: I use this code but it is not working properly... it is behaving same as before...
this is my redirect code after successful login
 router.push((router.query.from && decodeURIComponent(router.query.from)) ?? '/');
this is my HOC code where I put the query path as you told me to do...

Comment: actually it is redirecting to the page that I was while I want to go to any private route.. but I want to redirect to the private route automatically after login successfully like in react we can do this using react-router...while user wants to access any private route login component shows up and after successfully login the user automatically redirect to the private route he/she wants to access...can I do that in next.js without using next/auth?

Comment: from query storing the path of previous route. Like if I am in dashboard page and I want to go to profile page by clicking a button. And the profile page is wrapped by the HOC. So I want that when I am in the dashboard page and click the button to go to profile page, I should be redirect to login page if I am not logged in, after successfully login I want to redirect to profile page, but now I am redirecting to dashboard page.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. In the scenario you've just described, the `asPath` in the HOC will contain the path to the profile page (that's the page it's wrapping), so that's the page that should be redirected to after login. What path are you seeing in the `from` query param in the login page?

Comment: if I want to go to profile page from home page then I am redirecting to home page, if I am in dashboard page then I am redirecting to dashboard page, not to profile page.

Comment: https://github.com/jinglad/next-private-route
you can check this repo....

Comment: The `react-google-login` lib doesn't seem to work in that sandbox, but if I replace the `signIn` function with calling the `router.push` directly I can see the redirect working as expected.

Comment: sorry. I didn't get you. Where did you replace the code? can you provide me the changes?

Comment: In the login page, I replaced the `signIn` function passed to the login `onClick` callback with the the `router.push` call directly: `<a onClick={() => router.push(router.query.from ? decodeURIComponent(router.query.from) : '/');} className={styles.button}>`. So maybe `react-google-login` is interfering with the redirecting logic.

Comment: after doing that are you able to redirect to profile page after clicking the login button?
I am doing also the same as you mentioned but the behaviour is still same
I console log the from query. It is showing the previous route not the profile page route

Comment: @jin_glad Sorry, you are completely right - the issue was in using `Router.asPath` in the client-side navigation. Replacing the line ``Router.replace(`/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(Router.asPath)}`);`` with ``Router.replace(`/login?from=${encodeURIComponent(context.asPath)}`);`` should work as intended. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes in the authentication HOC.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working fine now...

Comment: hi, The redirect issue was solved but after that I am facing another issue. when I am in the that private route after successfully login, and hit the refresh then I am automatically redirected to the login page although I am login, is it normal behaviour or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: In `checkUserAuthentication` you check the `localStorage` to determine whether the user is logged-in. On page reload the HOC code runs on the server where `window` is not defined, so it redirects to the login page. Try using cookies instead to track the login state.