# How do I push user to another page using a button in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, next-router

I am trying to redirect a user on a button click in my nextjs app, pls how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect back from within the client code, or on the server side with Nextjs? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code you are trying to work with in a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I see, so you are asking how to make the UI code redirect back after authentication. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857 If not, then can you update your question to include all relevant UI code handling this authentication check and redirection to login route/component?

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [How to redirect back to private route after login in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689821/1870780)? You'll need to implement your own logic to redirect back to the previous page.

Comment: I want the user to return to what they're doing before redirecting them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later made this work by using router.push('/')
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router